# Error while quering using search.asmx Query or ex query method

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, query, soap

I am trying to query using search.asmx ex query and query methods using soap api's

> I am getting the following err "Data at the root level is invalid.
>   Line 1, position 1."

Please help .

```
I am following the format:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <QueryEx xmlns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/OfficeServer/QueryService">
      <queryXml>string</queryXml>
    </QueryEx>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Request:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><QueryEx xmlns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/OfficeServer/QueryService"><queryXml>OI-415954</queryXml></QueryEx></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

Response:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.</faultstring><faultactor>site anme/_vti_bin/search.asmx</faultactor><detail><error xmlns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/OfficeServer/QueryService">ERROR_BAD_REQUEST</error><linenumber xmlns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/OfficeServer/QueryService">1</linenumber><lineposition xmlns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/OfficeServer/QueryService">1</lineposition></detail></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

The query format should be similar as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <Query
            xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search">
            <queryXml>
            <![CDATA[<QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query'>
<Query><SupportedFormats><Format revision='1'> urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document:Document
</Format></SupportedFormats><Context><QueryText language='en-US' type='STRING'>OI-415954</QueryText></Context></Query></QueryPacket>]]>                
            </queryXml>
        </Query>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can u please tell me how to limit it to only items,ot return only items

Comment: You may create a scope to limit to list item only, and then query based on the scope, the tool https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=fastforsharepoint would be helpful for you to build the query.